# An object's movement, using sprite.body.moveTo, is interfered with on collision

Tags: phaser-framework

I am making a platformer, and I want to make something similar to [Thwomp](http://www.mariowiki.com/images/0/09/ThwompNSMBU.png) from Mario. So it's just an enemy that patrols between two points, and any collision with the player will kill the player.

I do this via Phaser's [sprite.body.moveTo](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#moveTo). I need to check if the enemy overlaps with the player, so I can trigger the player dying.

The problem is that, when the player and enemy collide, the moveTo is messed up, and the enemy's path is hindered. I took a short video to demonstrate what happens. [Video](https://youtu.be/LtHwAtEH1gM).

Here is the code for when I create the enemy. I use an object group from Tiled for the properties, so thats what all the `map.objects.mainObjecets[i]` stuff is.

```
//demons is a phaser group with body enabled.
var demon = demons.create(map.objects.mainObjects[i].x,map.objects.mainObjects[i].y,'demon');
demon.direction = Number(map.objects.mainObjects[i].properties.direction);
demon.distance = Number(map.objects.mainObjects[i].properties.distance);
demon.duration = Number(map.objects.mainObjects[i].properties.duration);
//I tried using stopVelocityOnCollide and immovable to fix the problem, neither one worked
demon.body.stopVelocityOnCollide=false;
demon.body.immovable = true;
demon.body.onMoveComplete.add(moveDemon, this);
game.time.events.add(map.objects.mainObjects[i].properties.delay, function(a) {
    a.body.moveTo(a.duration, a.distance, a.direction);
}, this, demon);
```

And here is the code that runs everytime a movement completes.

```
function moveDemon(demon) {
  game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * .3, function() { //.3 second delay before moving
    demon.direction = 360-demon.direction;
    demon.body.moveTo(demon.duration, demon.distance, demon.direction);
  }, this);
}
```

And lastly, here is the code for checking for overlaps

```
this.physics.arcade.overlap(player,demons,function(){
  //This code just moves the player back to the spawn point.
  player.x = map.objects.spawn[0].x;
  player.y = map.objects.spawn[0].y;
});
```

Comment: Hard to say really, but maybe something goes wrong with the body placements or body offsets.

To check this, in the create() you can do `mylayer.debug = true;` to see body of a tilemap. Or similarly, you can add a `render()` function, so next to the standard `create()` and `update()` functions. And in the render() function you can add something like `game.debug.body(player);` to see the body of a sprite in a green rectangle.
If everything is correct, the green collision rectangles should overlap with the sprites (the visual parts).

Comment: @BdR Maybe you misunderstood the question. The problem is that they do overlap, but when they overlap the enemy that is constantly moving up and down, messes up its path. In the video, you can see before the player overlaps the enemy, that the enemy is moving all the way up and down. But now that the player overlaps the enemy, it only moves a couple pixels up/down before switching directions.